# Is there a way to bind dart to lua?

Tags: flutter, dart, lua

Or is it possible to scripting in Dart/Flutter?
What I want to do is to run a snippet codes from a string or file, while have ways to interact with object/functions in original dart code.

I understand there's a official flutter library to interpret Lua string (https://github.com/drydart/flutter_lua), however that library could not allow me to bind Dart functions and objects to be used in Lua scripts.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Lua Dardo](https://github.com/arcticfox1919/LuaDardo) and follow [this example](https://github.com/arcticfox1919/flutter_lua_dardo/tree/master/test) to bind Dart and Lua.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so in the end I didn't use lua at all.
I choose to build my own script language and embedded it into Dart, to achieve the goal I wanted in the beginning: Two way binding(invoke script language function from host language and invoke host language function in scripting).

This is the script language I am currently using in Dart: https://github.com/hythl0day/HetuScript

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do this by using this extension in flutter :

```
flutter_lua 0.3.1
```

Comment: This embeds the actual Lua C implementation in Flutter via plugins. For a pure Dart interpreter for Lua, see LuaDardo from @Angelo Polotto 's answer.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/BlzFans/lua_flutter

bind dart to lua and typescript

lua_flutter\dart2lua can bind dart function or class to lua

```
--main.lua
local widget = Center {
    child = Text(
        "flutter_main", {
            style = TextStyle {
                fontWeight = FontWeight.bold,
                color = Colors.blue,
            },
            textDirection = TextDirection.ltr,
        }
    )
}
runApp(widget)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).